# How do I record multiple paths?

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, rosbag, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I view bag files of recorded autonomous navigation, the global plan, and local plan seem to all get recorded under the same topic, even though they are published under three separate topics. This causes the plan to flash constantly between the three. How can I record these topic separately?

For example my topics are:
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/global_plan
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/local_plan

And when I play back the bag file, the only topic is:
/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/global_plan

But the points from the local plan are saved in that topic as well as the global plan points.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12447/how-do-i-record-multiple-paths?/) by [Corey Montella](https://answers.ros.org/users/45/corey-montella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-12-23**:
Could you post the command you're using to record your bags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There recently was a bug in rosbag that recorded topics from the same node into one. It sounds like you triggered that.

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3755

You should update ROS or more specifically ros_comm.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Corey Montella](https://answers.ros.org/users/45/corey-montella/) on 2012-01-05**:
Thanks, updating it fixed the problem!